# jq extract data of json

Tags: linux, bash, jq

I have a file containing strings like :
`[{   "ip": "127.0.0.1",   "timestamp": "1631581369", "ports": [ {"port": 80, "proto": "tcp", "status": "open", "reason": "syn-ack", "ttl": 42} ] }]`

I tried the following command to get the output

`cat output.json | jq -r '.[].ip,.[].ports[].port '`

but the lines  are seprated:

```
127.0.0.1
80
```

need a string like :
`127.0.0.1:80`

I tried
`cat output.json |   jq -r '.[].ip,.[].ports[].port | join(":")'`

But i get error of running this command:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:69): Cannot iterate over string ("127.0.0.1")
```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
jq -r '.[] | .ip + ":" + ( .ports[].port | tostring )' output.json
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/MownPooeEt)
[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/rLxSv6PjqV)

---

Using `join`, it would be

```sh
jq -r '.[] | .ip as $ip | .ports[].port as $port | [ $ip, $port ] | join(":")' output.json
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/X573h6bNpB)
[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/XvBF-VKedz)

---

Both of these solutions work with multiple IP addresses and with multiple ports per IP address.

Comment: the first way you provide is kind of interesting, mixing the strings. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using string interpolation :

```
jq -r '.[] | "\(.ip):\(.ports[].port)"' output.json
```